# MongoDB $sort on $concatArrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to concatenate two nested arrays (using $concatArrays) into one new field. I'd like to sort the output of the concatenation (Model.timeline) by a property that exists in both sets of objects. I can't seem to get it working with $unwind. Here's the query without any sorting:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'id': id
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            id: 1,
            name: 1,
            flagged: 1,
            updatedAt: 1,
            lastEvent: {
                $arrayElemAt: ['$events', -1]
            },
            lastimage: {
                $arrayElemAt: ['$images', -1]
            },
            timeline: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    { $filter: {
                        input: '$events',
                        as: 'event',
                        cond: { $and: [
                            { $gte: ['$$event.timestamp', startAt] },
                            { $lte: ['$$event.timestamp', endAt] }
                        ]}
                    }},
                    { $filter: {
                        input: '$images',
                        as: 'image',
                        cond: { $and: [
                            { $gte: ['$$image.timestamp', startAt] },
                            { $lte: ['$$image.timestamp', endAt] }
                        ]}
                    }}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You need three pipeline stages after your match and project. First `$unwind`, then `$sort` and then re `$group`. Use the `$first` operator to retain all the fields.

```
{
    $undwind : "$timeline",
},
{
    $sort : {"your.sortable.field" : 1}
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        name : {$first : 1},
        flagged : {$first : 1},
        updatedAt : {$first : 1},
        lastEvent : {$first : 1},
        lastimage : {$first : 1},
        timeline : {$push : "$timeline"}
    }
}
```

Please note that this will work even when you have more than one document after the match phase. So basically this will sort the elements of an array within each document.

Answer (score 0):

Your $match and $project aggregation stages worked after I substituted `id` with `_id`, and filled in the  values for `id`,  `startAt` and `endAt` like so:

```
db.items.aggregate([
     {
        $match: {
            '_id': '58'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            '_id': 1,
            name: 1,
            flagged: 1,
            updatedAt: 1,
            lastEvent: {
                $arrayElemAt: ['$events', -1]
            },
            lastimage: {
                $arrayElemAt: ['$images', -1]
            },
            timeline: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    { $filter: {
                        input: '$events',
                        as: 'event',
                        cond: { $and: [
                            { $gte: ['$$event.timestamp', ISODate("2016-01-19T20:15:31Z")] },
                            { $lte: ['$$event.timestamp', ISODate("2016-12-01T20:15:31Z")] }
                        ]}
                    }},
                    { $filter: {
                        input: '$images',
                        as: 'image',
                        cond: { $and: [
                            { $gte: ['$$image.timestamp', ISODate("2016-01-19T20:15:31Z")] },
                            { $lte: ['$$image.timestamp', ISODate("2016-12-01T20:15:31Z")] }
                        ]}
                    }}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```